# InDesign: poor rendering of gradient

Tags: adobe-indesign, gradient

Is there a way one could improve the rendering of this gradient?

After creating a gradient swatch and applying it to a rectangle that fills the entire page to use as a background, the gradient looks bad so I would like to improve the quality of it and High Quality display performance doesn't change anything:

[image]

Comment: Could you describe what you don't like about it? I'm on a mobile device and I don't see much wrong with it.

Comment: Oh, hello @Vincent , well, I have added another image, the gradient has that stupid raster issue where the transition is not smooth as it should (or as I would want it). The color transition is made with obvious rectangles and it's not nice at all..

Comment: @Lucian Hello, sorry to say but changing from Typical display performance to High doesn't do anything to my gradient. It only improves the shapes and text.

Comment: @Lucian I have created a wetransfer link to it: https://we.tl/LxA6Bhqgp6 , it's a single IDML file with the **&** and the gradient. Thank you.

Comment: @Lucian Thanks, I hoped inDesign had some magical powers regarding gradients :)

Comment: @Lucian I don't have that power. I'm not a moderator :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Banding within gradients is often a result of color stops being too similar and long distances between stops.

Often, for print work, onscreen gradients will show more banding than a press will. Of course, this is of little help unless you get color proofs or chromakeys from your print provider to check the gradients before printing them.

Since InDesign offers little ability to disperse colors within a gradient. The best you can do is use color stops which are not so similar if possible, or decrease the distance between the color stops.

If you need a "background" gradient, it can often be better to create it in Photoshop where you can add a touch of noise or diffusion to break up any banding which may be present.

Comment: Argh.. I really hoped InDesign had some magical powers when it comes to gradients. While waiting for an answer I already started creating my bg in PS. Thanks for your answer! C'ya around!

Answer (score 0):

Comments above is wrong for that case. Although it's true Adobe have the worst vector gradients in the whole industry (no dithering), making it borderline unusable for professional modern design, in the above case there are plenty of room for a smoother gradient.

I know I would try to switch the rendering engine. But here's what I got with an old CS 5.5 on that desktop. CMYK colors help but stil:

[image]

Comment: Can you give more details in your answer, to make it more like an answer?